# Apply OAuth rules to only one app in an Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, path, routes, controller

I have one Ingress Controller routing to different apps (on the same host).
I want to set up ONLY ONE of the apps to have OAuth, how do I do that ? I can't find an example of my use case on the docs or on internet. Maybe it's because annotations are general to all the paths in the Ingress.
My constraint : keep all apps declarations in one Ingress file

Comment: Which [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) are you using ?
Why do you need to keep all apps declarations in one Ingress file ?

Comment: @matt_j Because I have so many apps. The rule I have is: all the apps in a host live in one Ingress file. So, one host => one file.  Also, I use the same template for different environments (Helm charts). So, if I in my Ingress I have all my apps declared, it's easy to deploy in another namespace.. only values change. It's straightforward and easier to maintain than having 30 Ingress files for 30 apps...

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor not really.. :/

Comment: @devio, could you please provide information about your Ingress Controller?